# How to use zcat | head on large file in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, fastq, zcat

Have large `fastq.gz` files in an s3 bucket and want to look at a few lines and check that their format is correct. Working locally I use `zcat <filepath> | head -n 8` which works fine, but on AWS to get the relevant filename I use `aws s3 ls s3://bucket_name/filepath/` and get something like `2022-04-01 3244653538 filename.fastq.gz`. Attempting to feed this filepath to `zcat` - with or without the datestamp and keycode - returns `No such file or directory`. I am an AWS noob and would greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Do you mean something like `aws s3 cp s3://bucket_name/filepath/ - | zcat - | head -n 8` ?

Comment: This worked! At the end it returns download failed...[Errno 32] Broken pipe but no big deal, it did what I wanted